# Why are objects apparently cloned by collection initializer for List<>?>

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code, why is `pdList[0]` null while `_propertyDetails` is a properly instantiated object? I was under the impression that I'm adding a reference to `pdList` that points to the same object as `_propertyDetails`, so after instantiating this object, both references should be non-null?

```
PropertyDetailsModel _propertyDetails = null;
var pdList = new List<PropertyDetailsModel> { _propertyDetails };
_propertyDetails = PropertyDetailsModel.Read(PropertyId);
```

Forgive me if I'm missing something basic; I've been battling to narrow my problem down to this issue for several hours, and my brain is tired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's (apparently) a reference type, so when you create `pdList`, the reference gets copied, but it is `null` at that point. Assigning to `_propertyDetails` later does not change the `null` reference that's already in `pdList`.

Answer (score 5):

When you initialise the list, it is not `_propertyDetails` that goes into the list, but **the thing that `_propertyDetails` is currently a reference to** (which is `null` in this example, but the point remains). Making `_propertyDetails` refer to a different thing later doesn't change what's in the list.

Answer (score 2):

`_propertyDetails` is not an properly instantiated object. It's not an object at all. It is a reference which points to nothing which is called `null` in C#. To get an object, you would have to write something like

```
PropertyDetailsModel _propertyDetails = new PropertyDetailsModel();
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you're getting confused between a variable and its value. You don't need to use lists to demonstrate this - it's equivalent to this code:

```
string foo = null;
string bar = foo;
foo = "Hello";

Console.WriteLine(bar); // Empty, as the value of bar is null
```

Changing the value of a *variable* is not the same thing as changing the data within an object that the variable refers to.